# Pandas multiple aggregations over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With `df.agg`, I can apply a set of functions to all columns simultaneously:

```py
df.agg([
   lambda: (x>0).mean(),
   lambda: (x>20).mean(),
   lambda: x.isna().sum(),
])
```

Because the functions are anonymous, the results name will simply say `lambda` which isn't helpful.

Of course, providing named functions resolves this:

```py
def gt_0(x):
    return (x>0).mean()

def gt_20(x):
    return (x>20).mean()

def n_na(x):
    return x.isna().sum()
    
df.agg([gt_0, gt_20, n_na], axis=0)
```

Is there a more concise way? Typically those functions are not complex at all and will not be reused.

Comment: You might want to have a read about [`Named Aggregations`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `agg`, you could construct a dictionary and construct a DataFrame from it:

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'gt_0': (df>0).mean(), 
                               'gt_20':(df>20).mean(), 
                               'n_na': df.isna().sum()}, 
                             orient='index')
```